# How to remove triple dots in a string?

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have a string like `"yes...I am Aaron"`. How can I remove the triple dots in Python?

Comment: It's not clear what the exact requirements are here. Should we remove every instance of `...` everywhere that it appears in the string? Should we remove only the first instance? Is the "triple dots" value *special* in some way? For example, is the answer about the unicode ellipsis symbol actually on topic?

Answer (score 18):

```
"yes...I am Aaron".replace("...", "")
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer by jamylak should do the trick, however, if you are using the ASCII ellipsis try this:

```
>>> s = 'yes\u2026 I am Aaron'
>>> s
'yes… I am Aaron'
>>> s.replace('\u2026', '')
'yes I am Aaron'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "1,2,3,... ,10"
>>> s = re.sub("\.\.\.", "", s)
>>> s
'1,2,3, ,10'
```

---

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.sub("[\.][\.][\.]", " ", "yes...I am Aaron")
yes I am Aaron
>>> print re.sub("[\.]"*3, " ", "yes...I am Aaron")
yes I am Aaron
>>> print re.sub("[\b\.\b]{3}", " ", "yes...I am Aaron")
yes I am Aaron
>>>
```

Comment: re.sub('\.{3}', '', s) would be better :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pandas, then use `Series.str.replace` like

```py
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('...', '', regex=False)
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'\.{3}', '', regex=True)
```

*Details*:

- `df['col'].str.replace('...', '', regex=False)` - here, the `...` is a literal string that is replaced with an empty string.
- `df['col'].str.replace(r'\.{3}', '', regex=True)` - here, `\.{3}` is a regex that matches three consecutive `.` chars.

Comment: Please don't read this much into simple questions. While it's fine to explain Pandas ways to do something with an entire set of data (and thus avoid explicit iteration), the question should actually entail the existence of some entire set of data. If we want to process one string, it would be absurd to wrap it in a Dataframe just to apply something like this.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I came here after googling "regex three dots pandas replace". Hence is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the string

```
s = "yes...I am Aaron"
```

Assuming one wants to replace the three dots by a space, there are various ways to do that, such as

1. Using string.replace

   ```
   s_new = s.replace("...", " ")

   [Out]: yes I am Aaron
   ```
2. Using the split method:

   ```
   s_new = s.split("...")
   s_new = " ".join(s_new) 

   [Out]: yes I am Aaron
   ```
3. Using regular expressions (with [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html))

   ```
   import re

   s_new = re.sub("\.\.\.", " ", s)

   [Out]: yes I am Aaron
   ```